# Connecting MongoDB instance (on Compose) directly to MongoDB on Bluemix

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, compose-db, dbaas, nosql

I am looking for a Tool or Tool Set that can connect a MongoDB instance (on Compose) directly to MongoDB on Bluemix to extract / and move data from a MongoDB database on compose.com to a MongoDB database on Bluemix Public.

Is there a way to do this i.e. are there any known best practices to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at using mongodump and mongorestore: https://help.compose.com/docs/mongodb-tools#using-mongodump-and-mongorestore

I know you mention "directly" (as in no middle man) but I don't think that's currently possible (e.g. copydb is not an option in these managed instances).

Comment: may be you should consider using the Secure Gateway bluemix service that work's like a vpn between your local server and bluemix.